# Powershell - How can I deal with this type of drop down in I

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPeoO.png)

How can I automate powershell to select the Company fro this type of dropdown because it's not a normal drop down but it shows values only once you start typing?

**For e.g.** in this case when I type C it shows Company. Refer the screenshot image above.

Following code inserts the value but it doesn't recognize it and gives an error asking to input value -

```
$test.document.getElementById("val1").value = "Company (Company)"
```

Below code which works for normal drop-downs doesn't work here -

```
$val = $test.getElementById("val1")
$val[1].selected = $True 
$val.FireEvent('onchange') > $null
```

Comment: Instead of setting the values in the form, what about just submitting a post with the values you'd like to submit?  This is normally a more reliable approach than IE Automation to submit a form.

Comment: `$test.getElementById("val1")` returns either $null or a **single** object, not an array. `$val[1]` therefore is wrong because there is no element 1 (the second element in the non-existent array)

Comment: @FoxDeploy How do I do that ?

Comment: @Theo - I know, just tried that as it works with normal drop downs.

Comment: I suggest you try to open developer tools and inspect the code. Also, try to post the sample code here. If the site is publicly available then you can share the URL. We will try to check and test it. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this would be to skip automating an Internet Explorer window in its entirety, and instead simple capture the network operation and perform that in your scripts.

It's covered in detail in this blog post ['Faster Web Cmdlet Design using Chrome 65'](https://foxdeploy.com/2018/04/02/faster-web-cmdlet-design-with-chrome-65/) (written by me) but to summarize:

1. Open Chrome, or the new Edge, then hit F12 to open Developer Tools, and check the box 'Preserve Log' and then the filter 'All' [image]
2. Browse to your site in question
3. Fill out the form
4. Hit 'Post' or 'Submit' on your site and look for the matching action in the network activity list.
5. Right-click and choose 'Copy As->Copy as PowerShell' and then use this as the basis for automating the form.

[image]

You'll end up with a PowerShell cmd in your clipboard that can be trimmed down to something like this, and is a great launching point for further automation.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://api.weather.com/v3/location/search?apiKey=6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e&language=en-US&query=90210&locationType=city%2Cairport%2CpostCode%2Cpws&format=json" `
    -Headers @{
    "method"="GET"
     "authority"="api.weather.com"
     "scheme"="https"
     "path"="/v3/location/search?apiKey=6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e&language=en-US&query=90210&locationType=city%2Cairport%2CpostCode%2Cpws&format=json"
      "accept"="application/json, text/plain, */*"
     "origin"="https://www.wunderground.com"  
  "accept-encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
  "accept-language"="en-US,en;q=0.9"
  "dnt"="1"
}
```

This is part of how we test web applications at scale at the big bank where I work.

#### Why use this approach?

In this approach, you're testing the actual network interaction on the site, rather than filling out a IE Window and submitting it.  It's generally dramatically easier to go this route, and will have a quicker time to viable output than dealing with the vagaries of JavaScript jQuery Validation and other front-end errors that can crop up.

Comment: Looks interesting, will surely try FoXDeploy. :-) Thanks

Comment: How do I understand the output here? Is there an option to display the output on browser too?

Comment: There is no browser.  When the page loads normally in a browser, it gets images, html files, etc and then somewhere there is a script that tells it to make a http request to a server to get the data, like the forecast or a users posts.  This is how the modern web works. Now, the idea is that instead of you loading a web browser, and having that load this page and all of the elements like images and scripts, you have PowerShell do *just* the one http request to get the data you actually need.

Comment: One more question, after requesting a page if it needs a username and password, can I pass the same using this script? Will it be one by one i.e., one http request to open page & 2nd to login? If possible, please share a sample page with syntax.

Comment: Make that a new question and mark this as answer if it helped you.  You follow up is too different to answer here.

Comment: Sure, will do that.