# Execute JavaScript in Firefox on command from PowerShell

Tags: javascript, powershell, firefox

I'm trying to make a Powershell app for an internal distribution. My users cannot install any developer tools, browser extensions, or executables, and neither can I.

Users need to visit an webpage and scrape data off of that page. Currently I can copy and paste code into the Firefox console that accomplishes this, but this code fails in IE due to browser support. Users will all have Firefox.

I'm attempting a Powershell front end to ensure wide user support. I have a GUI that can take a search term and navigate Firefox to the relevant page. However, I cannot find a method to execute my JS.

If I were using IE, I would have Powershell do:

```
$ie = New-Object -COM InternetExplorer.Application -Property @{
    Navigate = $url
    Visible = $false
}

Function ExecJavaScript($ie, $jsCommand, [switch]$global)
{
    if (!$global) {
        $jsCommand = "document.body.setAttribute('PSResult', (function(){$jsCommand})());"
    }
    $document = $ie.document
    $window = $document.parentWindow
    $window.execScript($jsCommand, 'javascript') | Out-Null
    if (!$global) {
        return $document.body.getAttribute('PSResult')
    }
}

$result = ExecJavaScript $ie $SomeJSCodeHere
Write-Output $result
```

but since my code fails in IE11, I can't do this. I can't find a similar method to do this with Firefox. The advantage of the above script is that is passes the results of the JS code back to Powershell where I can operate on it further or save results locally.

Comment: Does the JavaScript on the site load some content which wasn't there before?  If so, you can use PowerShell to trigger the same JavaScript action (an AJAX call) and get the results that way.  If this sounds like your situation, I'll walk you through the process.

Comment: The script has to run with a certain page loaded or I get a CORS error. If I attempt to do it from a Powershell version of the script with wget, the website Captchas me out. It uses vanilla XMLHttpRequests to make various calls to that site based on user input and scrape relevant data. Can Powershell do that?

Comment: See the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59864027/powershell-how-can-i-deal-with-this-type-of-drop-down-in-i/59883167#59883167 for an approach to extract the JavaScript call to use in PowerShell.